# bucket_properties.acceleration_configuration.error_put.denied.header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS and S3. I have created a bucket and trying to enable transfer acceleration  there. While doing so - I'm getting below error:

```
    bucket_properties.acceleration_configuration.error_put.denied.header
    After you or your AWS administrator have updated your permissions to allow the 
    s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration action, choose Save changes.
```

Attaching screenshot for more clarification:

[image]

Any suggestion about how I can fix this error? Also , I'm logged in with root user.

Also, I have checked - I have write access to this bucket:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You, as in, your IAM user/role which you are using must have the nessessery permissions to enable acceleration. From [docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html):

> You **must be the bucket owner** to set the transfer acceleration state. The bucket owner can assign permissions to other users to allow them to set the acceleration state on a bucket. The **s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration** permission permits users to enable or disable Transfer Acceleration on a bucket. The s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration permission permits users to return the Transfer Acceleration state of a bucket, which is either Enabled or Suspended.

The error message suggests that you don't have these permissions or you are not the bucket owner.

To check what permissions you have, you can go to IAM console->users and search for your user name. It will have permissions listed. Also check group you belong to.

Comment: I have created this bucket my own. How I couldn't have permission to this? Also, I'm logging with the same user with which I had created the aws account

Comment: @Shiwangini Are you sure you are using root/admin account? Becuase based on your question "how can I check (whoami) here and my permissions to further troubleshoot it?" it seems that it may not be the case.

Comment: The reason why I asked just to cross-verify in case I'm missing something - because I'm new to aws

Comment: I have this problem as well logged as root user, 
You don’t have permission to edit transfer acceleration details
"After you or your AWS administrator have updated your permissions to allow the s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration action, choose Save changes. Learn more about Identity and access management in Amazon S3"

Answer (score 0):

@shiwangini: if you have created the bucket with the same IAM user, you should be able to enable it.
Pls check the ownership and permission on the bucket.
bucket -> permissions -> object ownership
-> ACL - make sure you have Write access on objects and bucket acl.

Comment: Thank you @swaym for telling this. I followed your instruction and verified that I have write permission on this bucket.  Also, I have modified my question with permission screenshot

Comment: @Channa were you able to solve it finally?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. It doesn't make any sense since it's an admin user